# PayPalの取引詳細に配送先住所情報がない

Tags: paypal

PayPalの取引詳細に配送先住所情報がないですが。
どう設定すればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 十分な回答が付いているようですので、[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)という操作を行なって下さい。ご自分の回答でも承認できます。現在、このサイトでの広報活動に関して[利用者で議論しています](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2263/)。PP_MTS_Frankさんのご意見や、今後このサイトで期待される行動をされるおつもりがあるのか、など、ぜひ教えていただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

取引詳細に配送先住所情報がない原因は、マーチャントのウェブサイトから送られた下記パラメータが「2」に設定されていません。
ウェブサイトペイメントスタンダードの場合、「no_shipping」パラメータ、https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/
エクスプレスチェックアウトの場合、SetExpressCheckout APIの「NOSHIPPING」パラメータ
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

このパラメータが2以外に設定すると、配送アドレスがなくても決済できるようになります。
配送アドレスがないと決済できないように設定したい場合は、このパラメータを2に設定してください。

また、サードパーティーショッピングカートをご利用の場合は、上記パラメータの設定方法についてはショッピングカートに問い合わせてください。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask